# Sudden change in points

Tags: discussion, support

Today I see sudden change in my points for various posts. can anybody explain this. are we clearing up bogus account and removing points voted by them?

[image]

Comment: I have strong feeling that someone reached 125 points limit, and all minuses, that he/she put on your questions/answers earlier, are applied

Comment: @Himanshu did you reach to moderators out there to help this issue ?Please reach out to them and see what can be done here .

Comment: nope not yet but as you said I will reach to them. @MohithShrivastava

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I might need to talk to the network admins — it appears as though they're all legit downvotes. When I say 'legit' I meant they're not the result of an automatic operation.

This is a pretty clear case of serial downvoting which should get picked up automatically and reversed by the system within 24 hours. I'll keep an eye on it and if it gets missed we can raise it to the community team at SE to fix up.

Comment: It is resolved now. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: @Himanshu I've had serial downvoting get picked up on a smaller scale and eventually rolled back. Glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score 3):

For your Information:

On any Site which is part of Stackexchange, their background robots/scripts run which keep track of many unusual activities.

If any user which down votes or up votes to your question/answer very frequently, get noticed by the Stackexchange system (daily vote anomaly script) and the super moderator (human).

One of the steps which surely take place is:

1. Roll back all those down/up votes. System is enough clever to know which vote should be rollback. You or your voter will be notified.
2. Super moderator can delete or suspend your voter account. And there are good chances of it.

**One more thing:**
System can detect if you are doing a proxy voting or say a remote voter which upvote your posts. 
**Above 2nd step takes place in such activity.**